# Parse XML file in Unity C#

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine, xml-parsing

I have a little problem with parsing XML file to object in C#. Whole project is in Unity3D. So I have this XML file:

```
<Questions>
    <Question>
        <questionText>What is this?</questionText>
        <answer>blablabla</answer>
    </Question>
</Questions>
```

And this is my parsing class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System;

public struct Montage {
    [XmlElement("questionText")]
    public string questionText;

    [XmlElement("answer")]
    public string answer;
}

[XmlRoot("Questions"), XmlType("Questions")]
public class ConfigScene {

    [XmlArray("Questions")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Question")]
    public List<Montage> questions = new List<Montage> ();

    public static ConfigScene Load(string path) {
        try {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof(ConfigScene));
            using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)) {
                 return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as ConfigScene;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
             UnityEngine.Debug.LogError ("Exception loading config file: " + e);

             return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling this "Load" method in camera Object in Start() method:

```
void Start () {
    confScene = ConfigScene.Load(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Config/config2.xml"));
    foreach(Montage o in confScene.questions) {
        Debug.Log (o.questionText);
    }
}
```

The problem is that my questions list is empty and I didn't get any provided data into it. Do I make something wrong? Maybe someone made it before and know what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Firstly make sure your file path is OK. That is the file __config2.xml__ exists in path `Application.dataPath + "Config/"`. You may print the path in method `Start()`
Secondly make sure you didn't get an exception in method `Load()`. Exception is not re-thrown from there. You should check the Unity application log.

Comment: As I see the the path is ok, but when I logged whole Path Combine I get something like this: "F:/Unity Projects/Montage Game/Assets\Config/config2.xml". As you see one of slashes is backslash (before Config). Is that an error or what?

Comment: That path is obviously wrong. You cannot mix up forward and backward slashes. If you are on Windows all should be backslash and on Unix based systems it should be otherwise. For now you may check by concatenating the path manually instead of using `Path.Combine()`. What is your OS, BTW?

Comment: I am using Windows 10. I sended "F:\\Unity Projects\\Gra montazowa\\Assets\\Config\\config2.xml" as parameter in Load method. I used 2 backslashes because "\" is a special character and I get error. Also it doesn't help, still I can't get data into my question List.

Comment: Did you get any exception in `Load()`? Log the exception message (`e.Message`) inside the `catch` block in `Load()` (somewhat the way you did for checking path) or debug through the entire `Load()` method. Paste the exception message here if there is any.

Comment: No, there isn't any error in Load() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML file schema (*config2.xml*) and the XML serialization attributes in the corresponding class doesn't match. Your XML document's root element (`Questions`) and the questions list element are conflicting.

Change your `XmlRoot`'s `ElementName` (which is now *Questions*, line 16 in code) to something else (say *Root*). Accordingly change your *config2.xml* file's content: enclose the entire document within a `Root` element as shown below.

```
<Root>
  <Questions>
    <Question>
      <questionText>What is this?</questionText>
      <answer>blablabla</answer>
    </Question>
  </Questions>
</Root>
```

Deserialization should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I have to put an answer because I want to add some code here. So now I can run it and I get data. But my XML file is more nested. Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<MontageConfig>
    <Parameters>
        <Parameter>
            <mainObject>
                <name>tableTop</name>
            </mainObject>
            <connectors>
                <connector>
                    <name>bolt</name>
                    <count>4</count>
                </connector>
                <connector>
                    <name>spike</name>
                    <count>5</count>
                </connector>
            </connectors>
        </Parameter>
    </Parameters>
</MontageConfig>
```

And my class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System;

public struct Connectors {
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string connectorName;

    [XmlElement("count")]
    public int connectorCount;
}

public struct Montage
{
    [XmlElement("mainObject")]
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string name;

    [XmlElement("connectors")]
    [XmlElement("connector")]
    public List<Connectors> connectors;

}

[XmlRoot("MontageConfig")]
public class ConfigScene
{

    [XmlArray("Parameters")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Parameter")]
    public List<Montage> questions = new List<Montage>();

    public static ConfigScene Load(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigScene));
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                //Debug.Log(serializer.Deserialize(stream) as ConfigScene);
                return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as ConfigScene;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("Exception loading config file: " + e);

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is with connectors. I think I didn't make it properly. So I can't get any data into this Connectors objects. Do you know maybe how to fix that?

Comment: I just followed this description: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx
And now everything works!